# fill linq null data c# from previous line

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have bill details in list which contains the heading:
Account Numbers, Dates, Service Number, Charge category, Details, exgst, ingst, Detailsfill

Column :- Account Numbers, Dates, Service Number, Charge category, Details, exgst, ingst
 are unique  values but Column Detailsfill contains null. I want to allow my C# script to set values for Detailsfill where Detailsfill is null then insert data from previous row otherwise do nothing.

Note that Running total sets to 1 when detailsfill column has any text but continues to increment by 1 from 3 when detailsfill column is empty.

Below is the script I used.

```
var result_set2 = (from a in result_set1
                   join b in
   (from x in result_set1a select x)
on
   new {col1 = a.id, col2 = a.account, col3 = a.date, col4 = a.service, col5 = a.chargecat } 
   equals
   new { col1 = b.id, col2 = b.account, col3 = b.date, col4 = b.service, col5 = b.chargecat } into outer
      from tb in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where a.running_total1 !=  0
        where a.running_total1 != 2
        where a.chargecat != ""
                   select new
                   {
   running_total = a.running_total1,
   account = a.account,
   date = a.date,
   service = a.service,
   chargecat = a.chargecat,
   details = a.details,
   exgst = a.exgst,
   ingst = a.ingst,
   detailsfill = ((tb == null) ? "" : tb.details)
 }).ToList();

 foreach (var line in result_set2)
{
    mobilenet_writerfile.WriteLine(line);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a correlated subquery to populate detailsfill. This would be in the form of a select from a context with whatever parameters you determine fulfill your requirements. Example on second post of this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/18da37b0-b40e-444e-8ec7-7bd343e0c799/
Also you can find other examples here on stackoverflow: [Is it possible to create a correlated subquery in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225052/is-it-possible-to-create-a-correlated-subquery-in-linq)

More information would be required to write a contextual example but here is basically what it would look like:

```
Entities context = new Entities();
context.tbl.Where(t=>t.Id == someId)
    .Select(t=> new() {
        t.Id, 
        context.tbl2.First(tbl2=>tbl2.Id == t.Id).Value, //This is the subquery
        t.whatever});
```

Comment: Sorry I am not the biggest expert in reading linq queries could you offer a bit more advice and clarification or is there any added info I need to present?

the way I see it is such as

A1, B1, C1
A1, B1, null
A1, B2, C2
A1, B2, null
A2, B3, null

Comment: basically we need a way to relate a subquery to the parent, so in your example it would be detailsfill = result_set1.Where(df => df.account <= a.account && df.Details != null).First(); This is assuming that result_set1 can be correlated to the current account and that the results are ordered by account. To make this more correct you would need to determine how to correlate the subquery (grabbing the detailsfill) to the outer query.

Comment: the data is sorted I just need to replace the empty cells with the closest value above where it is not null in the same column. If you think of it in excel, Col A has Sales ID, ColB has Payment method. So in row, ColB for row 2 is empty if the payment method is the same as in colB for row 1 = Paypal, similaryl, row3 ColB is empty if its the same but there is value if the Payment method is Cash for that Sales ID. In excel, I would just offset the value by-1 Row and 0 colmn (-1,0) if ColB was null. How do I do the same in c#.

Comment: I think the problem is that each row is created without any reference to the rest of the set. You Excel example doesnt really work because it has all the data in a set already. In linq and in SQL each row is added dynamically to make up the set. Basically there is no way to say select the last row as there is no concept of that until the set is created. The only way I can think of to do what you are asking is to use a subquery.

Comment: I have been working with the sub query idea since you mentioned but I am frustratingly getting nowhere. How would you approach the problem? Humanly we can read it but how can I make the machine understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a normal operation of Linq to hold onto a previous value and then use it later. That's not to say you *can't* make that work with Linq, but it would be more straightforward to keep that logic outside of the sequence operation. Simply iterate over the results after the query is composed.

```
var item = results.First();
foreach (var obj in results)
{
    if (obj.detailsfill == null) 
        obj.detailsfill = item.detailsfill;

    item = obj;
}
```

Note: If the first item happens to contain `null` in `detailsfill`, you will not pick up a value until the first item in the sequence that *does* contain a value. To get the first such item up front, simply use

```
var item = results.First(o => o.detailsfill != null);
// loop below
```

Comment: Does not work. VS2010 says Error "1 Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.detailsfill' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: Define a class for the result, do not use an anonymous type. You can then make the property writable.